# Spark Kafka Consumer not consuming messages from topic

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Hi i am new to spark and kafka, I am writing sample code to consume messages from Kafka topic using spark,

```
object Init {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "ip-10-0-1-10.ec2.internal:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "12",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
      )
  val topics = Array("TestLogs")
  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  SparkConfig.streamContext,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
  )
  stream.print()
  SparkConfig.streamContext.start()
  SparkConfig.streamContext.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

When i run above code on my cluster using

```
"spark2-submit  --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar --class Init 
--master local kafkademo_2.11-0.1.jar"
```

Consumer is going into infinite loop prints no message, I am explicitly killing process by Ctrl+C

```
INFO consumer.ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values:
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    bootstrap.servers = [ip-10-0-1-10.ec2.internal:9092]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    enable.auto.commit = false
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    interceptor.classes = null
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    client.id = consumer-1
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    max.poll.records = 2147483647
    check.crcs = true
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    group.id = 12
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.key.password = null
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    session.timeout.ms = 30000
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
```

18/09/11 07:03:05 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.10.0-kafka-2.1.0
18/09/11 07:03:05 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : unknown

If i test using console-consumer it displays messages,

```
kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper ip-10-0-2-11.ec2.internal:2181 --topic 
TestLogs --from-beginning

INFO consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager: [ConsumerFetcherManager-1536650065051] 
Added fetcher for partitions ArrayBuffer([TestLogs-0, initOffset -1 to broker 
BrokerEndPoint(177,ip-10-0-1-10.ec2.internal,9092)] )
Welcome to Kafka APIS
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the issue that you have got may be because of the dependency issues but I can provide the sample working code where you will be able to listen to any topic.

```
import kafka.serializer.{DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}


object KafkaStreamingConsumer {
  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaStreaming").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
    val kafkaConf = Map(
      "metadata.broker.list" -> "ip-10-0-1-10.ec2.internal:9092",
      "zookeeper.connect" -> "localhost:2181",
      "group.id" -> "kafkaSparkStreaming",
      "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "1000"
    )

    val message = KafkaUtils.createStream[Array[Byte], String, DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc,
      kafkaConf,
      Map("TestLogs" ->1),
      StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY
    )
    val lines = message.map(_._2)
    lines.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

I am using spark streaming library to stream the data from kafka topics. Do let me know if you find any issue while using the above code.

Comment: Which version of Spark streaming have to be used. I am using libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.0.1" But getting not found: value KafkaUtils
[error]     val message = KafkaUtils.createStream[Array[Byte], String, DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder](

Comment: if its sbt build then libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.0" and for kafkaUtils you need to import the libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.8.1"

Comment: Thanks fir responding.., I used same above and ran on cluster. Still same issue. No messages are displayed.-------------------------------------------
Time: 1536666910000 ms
-------------------------------------------
Displayed

Comment: You can check on the kafka version. If your kafka version that you are using in 0.8 and if topic was created in other version such as 0.9 and 1.0 then you wont be able to listen to the topic because of Kafka version mismatch issue. This is the reason it is working in your local but not in cluster.

Comment: You can use getkafka processor of Apache Nifi which support all the three versions of Kafka i.e. 0.8, 0.9, 1.0. Even we faced the same issue so we moved on with Nifi

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. My problem was , There were no new messages in topic to consume. Its resolved

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that the topic TestLogs contains data, then if you have already consumed the messages with a group id 12, then you will received only new messages not already committed for that particular group id: in that case you can replay the topic by resetting the kafka offset for that group or simply change group id (e.g 13).

Comment: Thanks for responding. TestLogs  contains data I already tried with different group ids before posting question but no help.